# please solve my query, After starting the pipeline, need active network connection till completion of pipeline run

Tags: azure, azure-devops

please solve my query, After starting the pipeline, need active network connection till completion of pipeline runv

please solve my query, After starting the pipeline, need active network connection till completion of pipeline

Comment: anymore information？ what do you mean by `need active netwokr connection`? has the pipeline failed with error message? could you share some screenshots? Or do you mean `service connection` in `project setting`? [Manage service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Hemanth, Any Update?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, if your pipeline doesn’t refer to the resources on your local, you don’t need to keep your active network connectivity, and the pipeline will continue with the server agent of Azure DevOps in backend. And you could even change a device to check the pipeline progress.

So

1.Is the stuck task referring to some resources on your local machine?

2.In which step, does your task got stuck?